# How to get only most bottom folders name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have this list of folders:

```
    D:Sports/All/Outdoor/Swimming/1.jpg
    D:Sports/All/Outdoor/Footbaal/3.jpg
    D:Sports/All/Outdoor/Hockey/3.jpg
    D:Sports/All/Indoor/TableTennis/Men/9.jpg
    D:Sports/All/Indoor/TableTennis/Women/9.jpg
    D:Sports/All/Indoor/Snooker/1.jpg
```

I want to get the bottom folders name in C#. 
For Example:

- Swimming
- Footbaal
- Hockey
- Men
- Women
- Snooker

**There are thousands of sub folders with different name.**

Comment: @BrienFoss - Could you please elaborate, how this is "possible duplicate" ?

Comment: You are asking “how to get only most bottom folders name in C#”, that link I posted is to a question asking “How can I get the last folder from a path string”. You are both seeking information on obtaining the name of the parent folder which a file resides.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
System.IO.Directory.GetParent(@"D:/Sports/All/Indoor/TableTennis/Women/9.jpg").Name
```

Comment: There are thousands of sub folders with different name. I can't hardcode file path. Only root folder name is same

Comment: of course you don't need to hardcode path, this line is just an example, you should create a foreach loop and pass your parameter instead of hardcoded path

Comment: You mean, first I read all files in directory then get parent folder name of these. There are millions of files in different folders. And In one folder there could be dozen. With your approach, foreach loop will execute =  total of files instead of total number of folder that I am looking for. that could be 20 times less then files if every folder have 20 files average. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `Split`;

```
var pathParts = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"D:\Sports\All\Outdoor\Swimming\1.jpg").Split('\\');
var pathPart = pathParts[pathParts.Length - 1];
Output : Swimming
```

Comment: There are thousands of sub folders with different names. I can't hardcode file path. Only root folder name is same

Comment: You should iterate the files in a simple loop.

Comment: This is not efficient approach to read first files and then get folder names from these.